# Security Manager vetoes action in Greasemonkey Script!

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

I'm trying to prevent my Greasemonkey script from executing within IFRAMEs. I'm doing so by using `if (window.top != window.self) return;`. As soon as I insert that line right after the metadata header, the error console throws out a "Security Manager vetoed action" indicating this exact line of code. There's no additional information available.

I'm using Firefox 3.6.10 and the latest Greasemonkey extension. Oh, I'm new to user scripts but even after some time looking for an answer I didn't find anything at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greasemonkey has an own API, which allows persistent storage and cross-site HTTP requests. For this reason, scripts are executed in a sandbox and this API cannot abused.

To make your code work, use:

```
if(usnafeWindow.top != unsafeWindow.self) return;
```

Please note the `unsafe` part, you may want to review these pages:

- http://wiki.greasespot.net/Security
- http://wiki.greasespot.net/Avoid_Common_Pitfalls_in_Greasemonkey

Alternatively, wrap the code in a `<script>` tag:

```
(function(f){var d=document,s=d.createElement('script');s.setAttribute('type','application/javascript');s.textContent = '('+f.toString()+')()';(d.body||d.head||d.documentElement).appendChild(s);s.parentNode.removeChild(s)})(function(){
   /* code here */
}
```

Comment: Alright, that explains a few things. Generally, it looks like it's a good idea to avoid unsafeWindow but in this case there's no alternative. Works like a charm now. Thank you.

Comment: As an alternative, you can put your script in a script tag and append that to the document. In that way, you've no longer access to the GM API, and the script behaves as any script on the page. See example in my answer.